# Facebook access token for User Home Town batch request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get user hometown using facebook Graph batch request for around 1000 users?  What accesstoken needs to be sent and how can I get that access token?

Thanks in advance,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a user access_token you can retrieve the *active user's* hometown if you have asked for the **user_hometown** permission. You can also retrieve the *active user's friends* hometowns if you have asked for the **friends_hometown** permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/